# simple one variable polynomial function: finding coefficients

Tags: polynomials

Write down the values of the coefficient $b$ and $d$ for which the graph of $f(x)$ with equation $f(x) = ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d$ would be symmetric about the origin.

Because this is an odd function, it leads me to the bx^2+d=0 equation. I am not sure that I am on the right way to the solution.

Thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately, what you want is an *odd* function, not an even function.

Comment: you are right, I just miswrote it, it's an odd function, and I used the -f(x)=f(-x) condition.

Comment: The odd terms are $x^3$ and $x$.

Comment: -f(x)=f(-x)
-ax3-bx2-cx-d=a(-x)3+bx2+c(-x)+d
which leads to
0=bx2+d

Comment: if x can be any real number, b=0 and d=0 are the only solutions?

Comment: @TTomi Yes, since $bx^2+d=0$ must hold for all $x$, we must have $b=d=0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want that $f(-x)=-f(x)$ for any $x$. In particular, $f(-1)=-f(1)$, so
$$
-a+b-c+d=-a-b-c-d
$$
whence $b+d=0$. Similarly, you need $f(-0)=-f(0)$, so
$$
d=-d
$$
whence $d=0$.

The two conditions imply $b=d=0$. The function $f(x)=ax^3+cx$ is odd for any value of $a$ and $c$, so you're done.

Comment: Thank you egret!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are right. Its just that you are using the word even instead of odd.

Comment: Thank you SR810!